# How to track changes of a property of a model

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this properties on my model.

```
public class Student : BindableBase
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Fullname { get; set; }
     
     private bool _isSelected;
     public bool IsSelected { get => _isSelected; set => SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value); }
}
```

And in my ViewModel basically loads all the students and assigned it into the Collection.

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<Student> Students { get; } = new();
private List<Guid> SelectedIds { get; set; }

public override async Task OnActivatedAsync()
{
     var results = await _service.GetAllStudents(take: 100);
     Students.ReplaceRange(results);
}
```

And in my Xaml

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{x:Binding Students}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Student">
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Margin="0,20" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Binding IsSelected}" />
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="17"
                            Text="{x:Binding Fullname}"
                            TextColor="{x:StaticResource ColorBlack}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="Gray" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Now what I want to achieve is that whenever I select an item I want it to be added to a new List of items object right away. But for now I don't have an idea how to do such thing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

I can check who among of the students that has IsSelected = true by using Linq but this is during Save button. But what I wanted to do now is during check and uncheck it is being added/remove in a new List object, which is I'm having a hard time how to implement.

Comment: Catch the PropertyChanged Event of your class (When the SetProperty method is what i think it is)?

Comment: there is an entire section of [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection) on how `CollectionView` deals with item selection

Comment: @Ralf - Are you referring to the IsSelected property? This one is catching the changes if it's selected (true) or not (false). But I don't know how my ViewModel will know if those properties per student is changing so that I could be able to add it to the new List<Guid> object.

Comment: @Jason - When I tried to implement the method in my ViewModel and applied in my xaml it gives me an error "EventHandler "OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged" with correct signature not found."

This is the code I implemented on my ViewModel: public void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object send, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) { string selected = e.PreviousSelection.ToString(); }

Comment: event handlers belong in the code behind, not the VM

Comment: @Jason - Is there any other way implementing all in the ViewModel and not in the code behind?

Comment: yes, use Commands in the VM, not events

Comment: @Jason - Thank you for your reference doc, I was able to make it work using Commands. I just added the following command to my stack layout: <Stacklayout TappedCommand="{x:Binding Source={x:Reference StudentsTab}, Path=BindingContext.StudentDetailsCommand}" TappedCommandParameter="{x:Binding Id}">

Answer (score 1):

You must binding property 'SelectedItem' of CollectionView to property in model:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding View}" SelectedItem="{Binding> SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

And property in model:

```
public Student SelectedItem  
{   
   get 
   { 
       return selectedItem; 
   }   
   set   
   { 
       selectedItem = value;
       DoSomeActionWithSelectedItem(selectedItem);   
   } 
} 
private Student selectedItem;

private void DoSomeActionWithSelectedItem(Student student) 
{   
..... 
}
```

In function 'DoSomeActionWithSelectedItem' you can add to list etc.